# plm function in R: Order of input for index changes results when model = within?

Tags: r, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I am only slightly familiar with the `plm()` function in R, and I get this odd phenomenon.

When my input is this:

```
summary(plm(trust ~ u*SAP*euro, data = thesis, index = c("wave", "country"), model = "within"))
```

My coefficients look like this:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)   
u            -0.032216   0.218323 -0.1476 0.882746   
SAP1          3.822850  11.030372  0.3466 0.729046   
euro1         3.132854   2.815987  1.1125 0.266409   
u:SAP1       -0.203725   0.738879 -0.2757 0.782868   
u:euro1      -0.822703   0.272390 -3.0203 0.002645 **
SAP1:euro1   -8.547847  12.728400 -0.6716 0.502153   
u:SAP1:euro1 -0.106580   0.823753 -0.1294 0.897103
```

However, when I change `index = c("wave", "country")` to `index = c("country", "wave")`, that influences all the estimates by a lot:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
u             -0.61203    0.20672 -2.9606  0.003205 ** 
SAP1          11.00945    9.57049  1.1504  0.250504    
euro1          4.57873    3.09121  1.4812  0.139130    
u:SAP1        -0.51587    0.65099 -0.7924  0.428454    
u:euro1       -1.08519    0.27065 -4.0096 6.934e-05 ***
SAP1:euro1   -21.59497   10.68735 -2.0206  0.043810 *  
u:SAP1:euro1   0.68574    0.70375  0.9744  0.330288
```

Why is this? Shouldn't the `plm()` function run the exact same regression with two-way fixed effects regardless of the order in which I put in my two fixed effects categories (country and wave)? Which results should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the order when using PLM is that what you put first as the index specifies what you want fixed effects on.

Here is case fixed effects.

```
library(plm)
p.vdem <- pdata.frame(vdem, index=c("country_id", "year"), row.names=FALSE)

caseFE <- plm(v2x_polyarchy ~ e_reserves_billions, model="within", data=p.vdem)
```

Here is time fixed effects.

```
p.vdem <- pdata.frame(vdem, index=c("year", "country_id"), row.names=FALSE)

timeFE <- plm(v2x_polyarchy ~ e_reserves_billions, model="within", data=p.vdem)
summary(timeFE)
```

Two-way fixed effects are obtained by setting both variables to factor and generating dummy variables.

```
twowayFE.dummy <- lm(v2x_polyarchy ~ e_reserves_billions + factor(country_id) + factor(year), data=vdem)
summary(twowayFE.dummy)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! That would make a lot more sense. I had actually already done an lm() regression like yours, and already found it odd that the results were different when using the plm function. There is no way to do two-way fixed effects using the within estimator then?

Comment: @John Stud: Rwo-way fixed effects can be estimated evene without creating dummy variables directly with plm: use argument `effect = "twoways"`. Similarly, as long as the indexes are correctly set, one can perform individual (case) and time fixed effects separately, whithout switching the index variables, use `effect = "individual"` or `effect = "time"`. It is all documented, btw. First variable in index should be the individual (case) dimension, otherwise interpretation of `effect` switches.